# ¿Como optimizar consulta ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle

Necesito optimizar consultas para que tener un mejor rendimiento a la hora de buscar la data me esta tardando demasiado adjunto un ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la consulta estoy utilizando la base de datos de ORACLE

```
SELECT 
SM_ID,
ORIGINAL_ADDRESS,
DESTINATION_ADDRESS,
SUBMISSION_TIME,
FINAL_TIME,
SM_STATUS,
ERROR_CODE,
ORG_ACCOUNT,
DEST_ACCOUNT,
MO_MSC_ADDR,
MT_MSC_ADDR
FROM SMS_DATA_SMC
WHERE TRUNC(SUBMISSION_TIME) = TO_DATE('22/11/2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
AND MO_MSC_ADDR is not null
AND MO_MSC_ADDR NOT LIKE '569%' AND FINAL_TIME IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY SM_ID
```

Comment: Revisa lo de TO_DATE('22/11/2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY') , no concuerda el formato

Comment: Ya lo cambie igual tarda

Comment: Eso me suena a TOAD, no tiene algo para optimizar las consultas? (Nunca lo usé y no sé cómo funcionará, pero busca info). Aquí te van a decir que lo hagas a mano xD

Comment: Si es TOAD, jajaja si

Comment: Lo del formato era al margen de la optimización. ¿Hay índices en la tabla?

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con indice?

Comment: ¿Cuántos datos hay en la tabla?, ¿cuál es el plan de ejecución actual?

Comment: Diarios aprox, 12 mil registros, no existe un plan de ejecucion actual

Comment: Toda consulta tiene un plan de ejecución. No existe tal cosa como una sentencia `select` válida sin plan de ejecución.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Prueba con

```
SELECT 
SM_ID,
ORIGINAL_ADDRESS,
DESTINATION_ADDRESS,
SUBMISSION_TIME,
FINAL_TIME,
SM_STATUS,
ERROR_CODE,
ORG_ACCOUNT,
DEST_ACCOUNT,
MO_MSC_ADDR,
MT_MSC_ADDR
FROM SMS_DATA_SMC
WHERE 
FINAL_TIME IS NOT NULL
AND MO_MSC_ADDR is not null
AND MO_MSC_ADDR NOT LIKE '569%' 
AND TRUNC(SUBMISSION_TIME) = TO_DATE('22/11/2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
ORDER BY SM_ID
```

Así se filtra primero para eliminar campos con una comparación directa, y luego ya se compara la parte que implica llamadas a funciones.

Quizá debas crear índices para que no se tenga que leer toda la tabla para filtrarla.

Comment: Igual tarda ya lleva un minuto

Comment: Tendrás que crear índices entonces.

Comment: Como haria eso hermano

Comment: Echa un ojo al enlace http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/oracleya/simulador/simulador.php?cod=203&punto=45&inicio=

Comment: Ok lo voy a revisar..

Answer (score -1):

```
VARIABLE_FECHA:= TO_DATE('22/11/2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY') ;

SELECT A1.* FROM (
SELECT 
    SM_ID,
    ORIGINAL_ADDRESS,
    DESTINATION_ADDRESS,
    SUBMISSION_TIME,
    FINAL_TIME,
    SM_STATUS,
    ERROR_CODE,
    ORG_ACCOUNT,
    DEST_ACCOUNT,
    MO_MSC_ADDR,
    MT_MSC_ADDR
FROM SMS_DATA_SMC
WHERE MO_MSC_ADDR NOT LIKE '569%' 
AND TRUNC(SUBMISSION_TIME) = VARIABLE_FECHA
AND FINAL_TIME IS NOT NULL
AND MO_MSC_ADDR IS NOT NULL
)
ORDER BY SM_ID
```

Verás oracle ejecuta las operaciones del where desde bajo a arriba entonces cualquier sentencia que no involucre conversión de datos se ejecutara mas rápido
por lo tanto el oracle no tendrá que hacer n veces por ejemplo la operación que ahora esta en variable fecha tambien se reduce la cantidad de trunc porque previamente se redujo las filas al quitar los valores null

Finalmente una vez que se ha realizado la consulta solo ejecutas el orden a los resultados de la consulta en lugar de ordenar todos los datos y filtrar, filtras y ordenas

Si es posible deberías crear una columna con el trucn de SUBMISSION_TIME y luego crear un índice de este valor y por ultimo colocarlo al final del where, esto mejorara mucho tu consulta

Comment: ¿En dónde en la documentación dice que el where se _ejecuta_ de abajo hacia arriba? Una aseveración como esa debiera ir soportada por un enlace a la documentación o algún artículo que pueda considerarse "oficial" del fabricante. Lo digo, porque claramente [no funciona de esa manera](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9527899800346950291).